# error calculating common denominators

Tags: vb.net

This code gives a result of 1 for all numbers and i don't know why. phi(n) for any n in this code give me 1.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim n As Integer
    n = CStr(TextBox1.Text)

    Dim phi As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    phi = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        If (gcd(i, n) = 1) Then
            phi = phi + 1
            End If

    Next

    Label3.Text = phi
End Sub
Private Function gcd(ByVal num1 As Integer, ByVal num2 As Integer) As Integer

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim reminder As Integer
    Dim temp As Long

    If (b > a) Then

        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp

    End If

    Do While (b <> 0)

        reminder = a Mod b
        a = b
        b = reminder

    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: I'm not a VB expert, but does `gcd` return anything?

Comment: The function gcd doesn't ever access its parameters. The do loop in gcd will terminate immediately because b always equals 0. The for loop that calls gcd will never modify phi because gcd always returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing num1 and num2 to gcd, but not doing anything with them. Instead you're using a and b in there...which will default to zero...therefore the gcd function doesn't actually do anything. And even if it did, you've not told it to return anything based on the results of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `gcd` function takes `num1` and `num2` and ignores them, working instead with `a` and `b` which are not initialized and so are zero.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you set the value of the variables a and b in the gcd function?  I also don't see your gcd function returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `Return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use two textboxes to represent the numbers.  The label will contain the GCD.  This is an implementation of Euclid's algorithm.

```
Dim dividend As Long
Dim divisor As Long
Dim quotient As Long
Dim remainder As Long

    If Long.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, dividend) Then

        If Long.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, divisor) Then
'place in correct order
            quotient = Math.Max(dividend, divisor) 'determine max number
            remainder = Math.Min(dividend, divisor) 'determine min number
            dividend = quotient 'max is dividend
            divisor = remainder 'min is divisor
            Do
                quotient = Math.DivRem(dividend, divisor, remainder) 'do the division
'set up for next divide
                dividend = divisor 'dividend is previous divisor. if remainder is zero then dividend = GCD
                divisor = remainder 'divisor is previous remainder
            Loop While remainder <> 0 'loop until the remainder is zero
            Label1.Text = dividend.ToString("n0")
        End If
    End If
```